# Extracting the times when the data looks like this - 'Monday|7:00-17:00' in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, time

Is there a way to extract the starting time and the ending time of this type of text data in SQL? 'Monday|7:00-17:00'
I need to calculate the difference and get the number of hours.

I tried SUBSTR but since the days have different lengths MONDAY, TUESDAY, etc., it doesn't work.

Comment: Did the answer below help? Do you need additional assistance? If one of the answers helped you resolve the issue, I'd recommend marking the answer of your choice as accepted by clicking on the check mark by the answer.

Comment: I've added an edit that shows you how to do the same job that may work for your version of SQLite, which is over 10 years old of a version. Check out the edit at your convenience and let me know if it worked or did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Take a peek at this example: https://dbfiddle.uk/HyMsdfoJ

```
select dt
  , instr(dt, '|')
  , substr(dt, instr(dt, '|') + 1, 100)
  , instr(substr(dt, instr(dt, '|') + 1, 100), '-')
  , substr(
      substr(dt, instr(dt, '|') + 1, 100),
      1,
      instr(substr(dt, instr(dt, '|') + 1, 100), '-') - 1
    ) as starttime
  , substr(
      substr(dt, instr(dt, '|') + 1, 100),
      instr(substr(dt, instr(dt, '|') + 1, 100), '-') + 1,
      100
    ) as endtime
  from (select 'Saturday|9:00-11:00' as dt) t
```

You can change `select 'Saturday|9:00-11:00' as dt` to `select 'Mon|17:00-18:00' as dt` and try it again.

In the query above, I break down the problem by:

- finding the position where `|` exists. If the text was `Mon|17:00-18:00`, that'd be position 4
- extracting the text after `|` using substr, which would be `17:00-18:00`
- finding the position of `-` in `17:00-18:00`, which would be 6
- putting learnings from the above 3 items to get the start time

  - I take the text after `|` (17:00-18:00) and extract from position 1 to position 5
  - That gives me 17:00
- repeat a similar technique to get end time

  - I take the text after `-` in 17:00-18:00 by extracting 100 characters after position 7
  - 100 is an arbitrary number I chose. You can get more sophisticated with a bit of math and extract the exact length

Here's another example with a table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4f347/2/0

---

## EDIT - if you don't have INSTR

You could use this example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/9fcb6/1 if you don't have INSTR function.

You can try this at your own convenience.

```
select
  replace(
  
    replace(
      ltrim(
        'Monday|7:00-17:00',
        replace('Monday|7:00-17:00', '|', '')
      ), '|', ''
    ),

    ltrim(
        'Monday|7:00-17:00',
        replace('Monday|7:00-17:00', '-', '')
      ),

    '') as starttime,

    replace(
      ltrim(
        'Monday|7:00-17:00',
        replace('Monday|7:00-17:00', '-', '')
      ), '-', ''
    ) as endtime
```

Here's a stepwise showcase of how I got to the above method: https://dbfiddle.uk/RBffgB9q

Comment: thanks. it looks like it would work but for some reason, instr is missing from the version of sqlite that we're using.

Comment: What version of SQLite are you using @DenLim? It seems like you are using a version older than 3.7.15. 3.7.15 was released in Dec 2012 and that's when SQLite introduced INSTR (https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html#version_3_7_15).

Comment: I'm not sure. It's built-in into the coursera course SQL for Data Science.

Comment: @DenLim try out the latest edit I have made and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` functions to retrieve the hours like this:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR('Monday|7:00-17:00', INSTR('Monday|7:00-17:00','|')+1, 100);
```